# Change a text inside a symbol from the stage of adobe edge

Tags: javascript, adobe-edge

I want to change the text that is inside a symbol in Adobe Edge. the problem is that the text should load a text from a .js file.

Right now I'm using this code to do the same from a text that is in the main stage of the Adobe Edge.

```
var NameVar = $(nameOfWordsVarInTheExternalFile).find("NameOfTheText").text(); sym.$("name of the text").html(NameVar);
```

I'm pretty sure that is something that could be done just modifying the code above.

Comment: Finally I did it! the code is this one!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it!

here you are the code that works

var  NameVar = $(nameOftheChainWordsVarInTheExternalFile).find(name that we are looking for in the external file).text();
sym.getSymbol("symbolsName").$("textName").html(name that we are looking for in the external file);